# Missing push notifications

Tags: iphone, ios4, apple-push-notifications

My iPhone app's delegate has push notifications all set up:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {    
    for (id key in userInfo) {
        NSLog(@"key: %@, value: %@", key, [userInfo objectForKey:key]);
    }    
}
```

Now, I launch it, then suspend by pressing the home button. I then send a notification to the device, and the notification is received. A dialog appears with two buttons - "Close", and "View". Now, when I click "View", the app gets resumed, and didReceiveRemoteNotification is sent to the delegate.

But if I click "Close", the app remains in the background. If I then manually launch the app, neither "didReceiveRemoteNotification", nor "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" are sent. So - where is my payload? How do I get the payload in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the user closes the notification and launches the application using the app icon you won't get the payload anymore.. it is lost forever then.

This is described at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html in the "Handling Local and Remote Notifications" section.

Also notice that the server only saves one notification for your app for a user. If the device is offline and your notification is not received but you send another one the first one will never reach the user because it replaces the first one.